# In Realm can two query invoke my changelistener code concurrently?

Tags: android, realm

I am using `Realm` in `Android` now I have added a `changelistener` for my Realm query, now one thing I wanted to ask is as suppose I made two query and their results invoked my `changelistener` at the same time, now my question is can they call the listener concurrently at the same time or not.

I think as `changelistener` is calling in `UI Thread` So, I don't think at the same time two code can execute if they are in the **same thread**.

Can anyone please tell me is I am thinking in the right way or not ??

Comment: They're iterated and called one by one